# Размещение приложения в Appstore

Tags: ios, appstore, apple, ios7

Есть такая нестандартная ситуация:

Приложение работает с определенным интернет-сервисом, для чего, естественно, нужен логин и пароль. При отправке данных (логина, пароля) приложение предупреждает пользователя о том, что его персональные данные будут отправлены в "сеть", т.е. через инет на нужный адрес. Сам интернет-сервис не использует для авторизации никаких OAuth2 и т.д. Просто запрос-ответ.

Проблема в том, что Эппл не хочет принимать данное приложение, мотивируя тем, что:

> We found your app does not obtain user
> consent before collecting the user's
> personal data, as required by the App
> Store Review Guidelines.
>
> To collect personal data with your
> app, you must make it clear to the
> user that their personal data will be
> uploaded to your server and you must
> obtain the user's consent before the
> data is uploaded.
>
> iOS 8 includes keys for specifying the
> reason the app will access the user's
> protected data. When the access prompt
> is displayed, the purpose specified in
> these keys is displayed in that dialog
> box. If your application will be
> transmitting protected user data, the
> usage string in your access request
> should clearly inform the user that
> their data will be uploaded to your
> server if they

Т.е., кратко говоря, для них недостаточно простого предупреждения юзера.

Так вот, будет ли достаточно добавить стартскрин с описанием приложения, где будет указано о том, что приложение отправит в сеть его персональные данные. Что-то наподобие пользовательского соглашения.

Если кто сталкивался с такими вещами, опишите, пожалуйста, как вы их обошли. Спасибо.

Comment: Хороший вопрос. Правда, непонятно, что вы делаете сейчас: 

> для них недостаточно простого предупреждения юзера. 

Можно подробнее? Тогда станет яснее, чего Вам не хватает.

Comment: Опишите подробнее, о каких данных идет речь? Если о логине/пароле - ни о чем предупреждать, естественно, не нужно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ИМХО, надо предупредить о том, что вы собираете данные, а не перед отправкой. И дело, я думаю, не в пароле с логином, а в данных, которые получаете в телефоне, типа контактов пользователя и т.п.  
В правилах прописано про согласие пользователя на передачу местоположения, например. На SO есть топик про аналогичный отказ в публикации за передачу mac-адреса, и видимо, отловлено это дело было по вызову соответствующей функции.  
Так что надо определиться, что вы собираете и в какой момент будете уведомлять пользователя.